# View flashes then disappears when I use .save() with Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember Version: 1.2.1 and Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.5.

I am using the `FixtureAdapter` to store my data. If I use .save() and then transition to another route, the new view is displayed briefly then disappears.

If I do not use .save(), the data is displayed like I want it to. I need to use save() though because I need to be able to use `.find()` and `.findQuery()` later on.

You can see the code in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/21/) (with `.save()`) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/23/) (without `.save()`).

Here's the code with the `.save()`s.

The handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
{{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
<ul> <li> <button {{action loginGo on="click"}}>Login</button></li></ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="mainpage">
   Hello User! You have access to the following modules:
    <ul> 
    {{#each modules}}
       <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('mainpage', {
        path: '/mainpage'
    });
});

/* The mainpage router returns an object with the user's modules */
App.MainpageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
         console.log("Insite the mainpage route, user had access to " + App.currentUser.get('modules').toArray().length + " modules");
        return {
            modules: App.currentUser.get('modules')
        };
    }
});

/* Two stores. A User and the user's modules */
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    modules: DS.hasMany('module')
});

App.Module = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

/* When the user clicks the login button their User object is created
and assigned several modules, then we transition to the mainpage */
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        loginGo: function () {
            App.currentUser = this.store.createRecord('user', {
                name: "Bob",
            });
            App.currentUser.save();

            this.store.createRecord('module', {
                name: "Module 1",
                user: App.currentUser
            }).save();

            this.store.createRecord('module', {
                name: "Module 2",
                user: App.currentUser
            }).save();

            this.store.createRecord('module', {
                name: "Module 3",
                user: App.currentUser
            }).save();

            console.log("Right before transitioning to route, user had access to " + App.currentUser.get('modules').toArray().length + " modules");

            this.transitionToRoute('mainpage');
        }
    }
});
```

Clicking the Login button will run loginGo action which initializes a user object and 3 module objects. It then transitions to the mainpage route which should return the 3 modules and display them in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until the user is finished saving before adding the modules to it

http://jsfiddle.net/6Evrq/25/

```
        App.currentUser.save().then(function(){
          self.store.createRecord('module', {
            name: "Module 1",
            user: App.currentUser
          }).save();

          self.store.createRecord('module', {
            name: "Module 2",
            user: App.currentUser
          }).save();

          self.store.createRecord('module', {
            name: "Module 3",
            user: App.currentUser
          }).save();

          console.log("Right before transitioning to route, user had access to " + App.currentUser.get('modules').toArray().length + " modules");

           self.transitionToRoute('mainpage');
        });
```